# Splitting of de Rham cohomology for singular spaces

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, cv.complex-variables, complex-geometry, cohomology

I am currently trying to wrap my head around the following splitting result by Bloom & Herrera ([here](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/226554588_De_Rham_cohomology_of_an_analytic_space) is a link to the ResearchGate publication) for the de Rham cohomology of (in particular) a complex analytic space. The following Theorem is essentially stated as Theorem 3.11. in the reference.

**Theorem** Let $X$ be an analytic space and $\phi$ a family of supports. Then there exists a canonical splitting

$H^p_{DR,\phi}(X,\mathbb{C})\cong H^p_{\phi}(X,\mathbb{C})\oplus A^p_{\phi}(\mathbb{C}).$

where $H^p_{DR,\phi}(X,\mathbb{C})$ denotes the de Rham cohomology groups and $H^p_{\phi}(X,\mathbb{C})$ the classical cohomology groups.

The splitting in this theorem is induced by constructing an integration morphism from de Rham cohomology to classical cohomology. Before reading the paper I wanted to "get a feel" for this theorem and there my question arises.

Is it fair to say that this theorem says that if $H^p_{\phi}(X,\mathbb{C})=0$ then for every closed $p$-form $\alpha$ on a reduced $X$ there exists a $(p-1)$-form $\beta$ and a torsion $p$-form $\gamma$ such that $\alpha = d\beta + \gamma$? By a torsion form I mean a section of the cotangent sheaf such that the germ at every point of $X$ is eliminated by a regular element of the stalk of the structure of $X$.

This cohomology business is not my usual area so I want to make sure I do not misinterpret the result.

Comment: I don't like following random unnamed links. I assume you are talking about Bloom-Herrera?

Comment: @DonuArapura Yes, I am. I have also edited the question to be more transparent about the link.